# SQL-Server - Что такое SARG аргумент?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое SARG аргумент и как оптимизатор его использует?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SARG = Seekable ARGument, такой аргумент, при подстановке которого в условие `WHERE` позволяет использовать индекс. Например:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 3;
```

сможет использовать индекс по полю id, а :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (id * 3) = 3;
```

нет, так как потребуется домножить каждое значение id в таблице, что равнозначно полному перебору. NonSARG может здорово затормозить выполнение ваших запросов, особенно часто такие аргументы получаются в результате каста значений кортежа к другому типу.

Comment: Он же вроде бы Search Argument, значит он является внутренним параметром (так как не видно SAGR запрос или NonSARG) оптимизатора для определения возможности использования индекса?

Comment: @WizarD51 1. Search/Seek - синонимы :) 2. Для NonSARG оптимизатор просто не сможет использовать индекс. Или я не понял ваших затруднений?

Comment: Все ок, спасибо)